# Tabs background and font color change when click

Tags: html, css

I have a tabbed pane in my HTML page. The following changes has to done in the task.

1. When select a tab or hover, background - white, text color - #6baed9, border - 1px same color as text.
2. When tab is unselected (if selected the another tab this become unselected one) - background - #6baed9, text color - white,  border - 1px same color as text.

My CSS are as following,

```
#my_settings ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    height:35px;
    width:250px;
    color: #6baed9;
}

#my_settings ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6baed9;
    border: 1px solid #6baed9
}

#my_settings ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6baed9;
    border: 1px solid #6baed9
}
```

Issues I have :

1. In this when is case 2 above, I cant get the white text color when tab is not selected.
2. The border of the selected tab is fine but the bottom line is not showing.Why is that.

Please help me to do this.

**PS : When I try to change `#my_settings ul.tab li a {` to `color : #fff`, works fine. But when I click somewhere in the page the selected tab's color(#6baed9) trun to white.**

Comment: You've set color property to  #6baed9 in every case, this stands for font color, just change it to #fff

Comment: @SandeshK check my edit

Comment: you can use javascript for changing the color after click

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".tab").click(function() {
  $(".tab").removeClass('selected')
  $(this).addClass('selected')
})
$(".tab").hover(function() {
  $(".tab").removeClass('selected')
  $(this).addClass('selected')
})
```

```css
.tab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #3be9a6;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left
}
.selected {
  background: #3b6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>
<div class="tab">4</div>
<div class="tab">5</div>
<div class="tab">6</div>
<div class="tab">7</div>
```

you can use set up like snippet above.use jquery to insert class wich has the property that you want to have changed on hover or click.

Comment: how can change the `selected` text color ?

Comment: add color: "your selected color" to .selected  selector in css

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `<li class="active">`  for the active tab?